# Obtaining California SOS number for out-of-state LLC

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business, limited-liability-company

I own a Nevada LLC and will start doing some business in California this year. However, it seems to pay the California Franchise Tax, I need an SOS number for California (I could be wrong, but Google searches have not turned anything up yet).

If I need an SOS number from California, how and where do I obtain it?

If I do not, how would I pay the $800 California Franchise Tax?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

SOS stands for Secretary of State. The California Department of State handles the business entities registration, and [the website is here](http://www.sos.ca.gov/business-programs/business-entities/). See "Forms" in the navigation menu on the left. Specifically, you'll be looking for [LLC-5](http://bpd.cdn.sos.ca.gov/llc/forms/llc-5.pdf).